# Ionic Uncaught (in promise): invalid link tabs

Tags: ionic3, angular5

I have got this famous error from my Ionic3 Angular5 app. I have read a lot other posts on the same error but it seems those solutions can't help with my problem.

The structure of the classes:

- AppModule is the main module of the app, to be bootstraped in main.ts
- SmashApp is the main class defined in app.component.ts, "forRoot"
  inside AppModule in a eager loading way. SmashApp in the constructor
  also define "tabs" as the rootPage.
- TabsPageModule "forChile"
  TabsPage in a lazy loading way.
- TabsPage is an IonicPage and has a    name "tabs".

code:
app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SmashApp,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(SmashApp, {}, {
      links: [

      ]
    }),
    /*TabsPageModule,*/
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    SmashApp,

  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler },
    ConferenceData,
    UserData,
    InAppBrowser,
    SplashScreen
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
@IonicPage()/*this might not be necessary*/
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.template.html'
})
export class SmashApp {

  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;


  rootPage: string  = 'tabs';

  constructor(
    public events: Events,
    public userData: UserData,
    public menu: MenuController,
    public platform: Platform,
    public confData: ConferenceData,
    public storage: Storage,
    public splashScreen: SplashScreen
  ) {

    this.rootPage = 'tabs';
    this.platformReady();
.
.
```

tabs.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TabsPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(TabsPage),
  ],
  exports:[
    TabsPage
  ],
})
export class TabsPageModule {}
```

tabs.ts

```
@IonicPage({
  name: 'tabs',
})
@Component({
  selector: 'page-tabs',
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html',
})
export class TabsPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad TabsPage');
  }

}
```

Comment: have you imported the page module or tabspage anywhere ?example `/*TabsPageModule,*/`

Comment: @SurajRao The only place of import is in app.module.ts, but commented out.

Comment: Have you tried simply restarting ionic serve? Sometimes if you mess around with the project folders (add or delete some files), it gives that error. After restarting the client, it works again most of the time.

Comment: @Chris Yes. I have tried restarting it by "ionic serve"

Comment: Hm, just had a look on my lazy load pages. I just have '''@IonicPage()''' in them, without specifying the name. If you remove the name there, does it help? You would have to call it by 'TabsPage' then of course.

Comment: @Chris I think I have tried taken out the name and refers it as 'TabsPage'. But maybe I did not restart ionic. I will try it later today.

Comment: @Chris doesnt actually make a difference.